# My page takes 3-5 whole minutes to load, how can I possibly reduce it?

Tags: php, html, laravel, runtime, laravel-blade

I'm currently working on this project and the main page takes nearly 5 whole minutes to load. I've been trying to reduce the runtime, but I'm still new to programming and I'm not too familiar with pthreads, but I was told pthreads wouldn't work with this. Can someone help me figure out how to run this code faster and stop Chrome from killing the processor?

Also I know my PHP code is a bit messy, was planning on cleaning it up later, but the little bits of PHP code are around lines 0, 270, 420, 560, etc throughout the entire page.

Thank you for your time.

Here's a snippet of the code, but you can find the entire code in the pastebin linked below:

```
<?php $k = 0; ?>

<tr>
    @foreach($mondays as $monday)
    <?php $shift_worker_id = DB::table('schedule')->where('id', $monday->id)->value('shift_worker_id') ?>
    <?php $zone_id = DB::table('schedule')->where('id', $monday->id)->value('zone_id') ?>
    <?php $zone = DB::table('zone')->where('id', $zone_id)->value('name') ?>
    <?php $worker_id = DB::table('shift_worker')->where('id', $shift_worker_id)->value('worker_id') ?>
    <?php $shift_id = DB::table('shift_worker')->where('id', $shift_worker_id)->value('shift_id') ?>
    <?php $time = DB::table('shift')->where('id', $shift_id)->value('time') ?>
    <?php $type = DB::table('shift')->where('id', $shift_id)->value('type') ?>
    <?php $name = DB::table('worker')->where('id', $worker_id)->value('name') ?>
    @if($type == "Graveyard")
        <th style="font-size:11px" colspan="1">{{$name}}</th>
        <th style="font-size:7px" colspan="1">{{$time}}</th>
        <th style="font-size:11px" colspan="1">{{$zone}}</th>
        <th colspan="1"></th>
        <th colspan="1"></th>
        <th colspan="1"></th>
        <?php $k++; ?>
    @endif
    @if($k % 4 == 0)
        </tr>
        <tr>
    @endif
    @endforeach
</tr>
```

https://pastebin.com/uUGrs1x0

Comment: How many DB queries do you run on one page load?

Comment: use laravel debugbar and see how many queries are run on the page load and see if you can reduce them

Comment: Oh dear, there seems to be almost 8000 queries, that's not normal right @DhavalChheda

Comment: I'd consider that to be "a bit" too much. In the code you posted you have 8 times x queries, so if you have 1000 mondays you will generate 8000 queries. Whatever you're doing you need to find a way to combine queries, you can join tables you need and query for an array of monday ids instead of fetching them in each iteration of the loop, etc

Comment: @Quazi you should learn about eager loading and about working with Eloquent collections. A normal number of queries is 6 for this code.

Comment: yes @Quazi .. you need to improve your queries..

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely because of N+1 problem. Learn how to use eager loading.

You're creating a lot of redundant queries to the DB inside the loop, probably thousands instead of just 6.

> Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model. Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: So instead of how I query the call I would rather do it all in one go? Like replace those 8 <?php ?> lines with something that can be done in one go?

Comment: @Quazi yes, you need to create Eloquent relationships and then get all the data with one Eloquent query which will create just 6 queries to the database. If you've never used Eloquent, you should start from the official docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships