# SQLSTATE[42S22] Error when trying to eager load

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have a page that currently takes 5 minutes to load. After a recent post I found out that there's almost 8000 query calls and the users told me to use eager loading, so I've tried to get it to work but for some reason I keep getting an error. Does anyone know how I'd go about fixing this? Thank you in advance!

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'shift_worker.schedule_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `shift_worker` where `shift_worker`.`schedule_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319))

Here's the code I'm running in view:

```
<?php

$workers = \App\Schedule::with('shift_worker')->get();

foreach ($workers as $worker) {
    echo $worker->shift_worker;
}
```

Here are all my models and tables:

Worker Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Worker extends Model
{
   /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */

    protected $table = 'worker';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function shift_worker()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ShiftWorker');
    }

}
```

Worker table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('worker', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Shift Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shift extends Model
{
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
    protected $table = 'shift';


    public function shift_worker()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ShiftWorker');
    }
}
```

Shift Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('shift', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('time');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

ShiftWorker Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ShiftWorker extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'shift_worker';

    public function schedule(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Schedule');
    }
}
```

ShiftWorker Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('shift_worker', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('worker_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('worker_id')->references('id')->on('worker')
            ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');


        $table->integer('shift_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('shift_id')->references('id')->on('shift')
            ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->boolean('monday');
        $table->boolean('tuesday');
        $table->boolean('wednesday');
        $table->boolean('thursday');
        $table->boolean('friday');
        $table->boolean('saturday');
        $table->boolean('sunday');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Schedule Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Schedule extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'schedule';

    public function shift_worker()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ShiftWorker');
    }

    public function zone()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Zone');
    }

}
```

Schedule Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('schedule', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        //Assign workers shift_worker to
        $table->integer('shift_worker_id')->unsigned();

        //Zone they can work
        $table->integer('zone_id')->unsigned();

        $table->string('day');

        //Date the person can work
        $table->date('date');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh is that what it means? Should I just create a column and then migrate it or do I have to change the code so it doesn't read schedule_id?

Comment: hmm what are you trying to do ?

Comment: In my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877277/my-page-takes-3-5-whole-minutes-to-load-how-can-i-possibly-reduce-it),  I was told to reduce the load time of the website by eager loading since by the end of the call there's around 8000 query calls. I'm just trying to test eager loading and learn it before I use it in my main code

Comment: public function shift_worker()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ShiftWorker', 'schedule_id');
    } add schedule _id on both belongs to many

Comment: Just tried that and I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Schedule to ShiftWorker model should be a belongsTo, since you have the `shift_worker_id` on it

```
public function shift_worker()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ShiftWorker');
}
```

Also the zone should be a belongsTo relation

```
public function zone()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Zone');
}
```

Don't checked if there are wrong relations in the other models, you need to check that out and clarify your concepts through the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) and tutorials

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to shave it down from 8000 calls to 12!